# How do you list the folder permissions of only certain directories that follow a common pattern in a particular directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, ls, wildcards

For example, in the /etc/ directory there are several files named rc0.d, rc1.d, rc2.d, rc3.d etc

lets say you want to list the permissions or the sizes of these directories while ignoring other directories that exist within /etc/

If we use that particular case, I've tried `ls -al /etc/ | grep 'rc*.d'` this does not give the desirable output, I have also tried `ls -al /etc/ | grep 'rc?.d'` which outputs nothing at all.
if I do something like `ls -al /etc/rc*?.d` this will instead list the files or directories that are within these directories not the directories themselves which is expected but it was a try.

The desired output would be something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:11 rc0.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:11 rc1.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:24 rc2.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:24 rc3.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:24 rc4.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:24 rc5.d  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  6 03:11 rc6.d
```

Would appreciate some guidance, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `-d` option to make `ls` list directories themselves, not their contents. Ex.

```
ls -ld /etc/rc?.d
```

or

```
ls -ld /etc/rc[0-9].d
```